# JetBrains wrong syntax in Vue templates

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a problem with syntax highlighting in Vue files in my PhpStorm.

To start with I misclicked some keyboard shortcut and instead of highlighting proper Vue template syntax, my IDE highlights SQL Syntax. I have no idea how to fix this in other way than reseting all my settings, but I do not want to do that.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of how it looks (the whole editor tab -- I want to see the editor area + file icon).

Comment: Done: I had to change Language Injections. Closed